# How to initialize ViewModel with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Tags: maui, freshmvvm, maui-community-toolkit, community-toolkit-mvvm

We have a Xamarin.Forms app with FreshMvvm. Now, as Xamarin.Forms will not get support beginning next year, I am re-writing the app with .Net Maui. For MVVM pattern, I am trying to use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. But I wonder how I can initialize the viewmodel now. With FreshMvvm I could override Init(), but CommunityToolkit.Mvvm does not seem to have anything like this. What is the right way to initialize the viewmodel asynchronously, as there is no async constructor?

Comment: *"right way to initialize the viewmodel asynchronously"* What do you mean? Perhaps show a snippet of code, with a comment where you would add the "asynchronous" construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with .net Maui a weeks ago and also needed the possibility to run async code in the constructor of the view model. I found the method `SafeFireAndForget` from `AsyncAwaitBestPractices` ([nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncAwaitBestPractices)). The async code will run in a different thread and the constructor may will complete before the async method.

Answer (score 0):

In `FreshMVVM`, since the model has impelmented the `FreshBasePageModel`, you can override the `Init()` method and initialize data like the pseudo code below:

```
   public override void Init (object initData)
    {           
      //initialize data
    }
```

However, in `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`, you can set the data whatever you want in the default constructor like below:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = vm;

        Initialize();
    }
    public async void Initialize()
    {
        //await operation
    }

}
```

Official reference link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to call several async methods, so it would be good if I could call them from an async method. But constructor cannot be asynchronous.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can add an `async` method `Initialize();` in VM and then perform the `await` action.

Comment: But as Initialize() is called synchronously, does it matter that it is async?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: May Then the goal won't be reached...