# Switch from Xamarin Forms FreshMVVM to MAUI CommunityToolkit.MAUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit, freshmvvm

I am currently working on the migration from XF to Maui for our app.
I also want to change from FreshMVVM to the CommunityToolkit.MVVM.

Before, I had the Init function with some InitData, e.g.

```
public override void Init(object initData)
{
     base.Init(initData);

     if( initData is TextInfoViewModel model )
     {
         Heading = model.Heading;
         HeaderTitle = model.HeaderText;
         Text = model.Text;
     }
 }
```

and this data is given through this:

```
this.CreateNavigationCommand<AccountAboutPageModel>(false, true, ETransitionType.SlideFromRight, vm);
```

How can I do this with the Toolkit MVVM?

Comment: FreshMVVM is an MVVM framework, whereas community toolkit is a MVVM helper library, they are not the same i am not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve here

Comment: I refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73082466/how-to-initialize-viewmodel-with-communitytoolkit-mvvm?rq=2

Here is suggested to call the Initialize function in the constructor. But how do I do this when I have some data that should be passed to the new Page?